# Conditional Routing and Conditional Rendering in ReactJS and React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a question, I tried looking online and couldn't find what I needed but that's probably because I couldn't word my question properly.

I have a React project I'm putting together and I want to have user profile pages for people. Here is what I have so far.

```
<Route path="/profile/:user" render={(routeProps) => (<Profile {...routeProps} {...this.state} /> )}/>
```

This is in my index.js, to set the route for my profile pages for different users and the following is what I have for my profile page

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export class Profile extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            user: this.props.user,
            fullname: this.props.fullname,
            picture: this.props.picture
        };
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>{this.state.fullname}</h1>      
        );
    }
}
```

Now the question I have is this. I want the profile page to only load and render the users full name if the URL matches the userID given by 'user' in the state

in my index.js I have hardcoded user and fullname values to test this, they are set like this

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user:"AFC12345",
            fullname:"Bob Ross"
        };
```

I want to only have the Profile page rendered when I visit "http://localhost:8080/#/Profile/AFC12345" currently it renders the profile page for any "Profile/xxxx" I go to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way would be to consider that `Profile`container as a protected URL and use the same dynamic as the authentication flow.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedProfile = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={ props => (
     props.user === props.match.params.user ? (
      <Component {...props} /> ) : (
       <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/404' }} /> )
      )} />
 );
```

Then in your App/index.js

```
 <ProtectedProfile path="/profile/:user" component={Profile} />
```

Answer (score 1):

i would do something like this in the render function

`let viewToRender`

```
if (this.state.user === this.props.match.params.user) {
  viewToRender = <p>{this.state.fullname}</p>
}else{
  viewToRender = <p>Ids don't match</p>
}
....
return (){ viewToRender }
```